# Fail to compare whitespace from Tkinter text widget to one in python code

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to compare the text input in the text widget area with a predefined list of characters in my code so that it highlights in red the ones who are not in the list.

So far it's almost working just I can't understand why it fails to recognize a whitespace " " from the text widget as the same as the one in my list of reference.

There is a code example below.
The two lists 'alphabet' and 'punctuation' contain characters that I don't care about and don't want to highlight.
The list 'numbers' contains certain numbers that when found in the text will not be highlighted. All other numbers will be displayed in red.

So for example if I type '1a4a' then hit the 'Check' button, 1 will turn red and 'a', 4, 'a' won't change. Same applies if I use punctuation to separate the numbers except if I use a blank space.
Why is that? Is it because of some encoding reason, a whitespace in the text widget and in the python code is different?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

alphabet=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
punctuation= ['.', '(', ')', '[', ']', ',', '!', '?', '"', "'", ' ']
numbers=['2', '4','6','8', '12', '14']
class MyFrame(Frame):
    def verify(self):
        self.content=self.main_text.get("1.0", 'end-1c')
        self.main_text.delete('1.0', END)
        nums=""
        self.content.encode('utf-8')
        text_split = list(self.content)
        for item in text_split:
            if item not in (alphabet or punctuation_list):
                nums += item
            else:
                if nums in numbers:
                    self.main_text.insert(END, nums)
                else:
                    self.main_text.insert(END, nums, "red")
                self.main_text.insert(END, item)
                nums=""
        return 'break'

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.title("Verif")
        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid(sticky=W+E+N+S)

        self.Frame_buttons = Frame(master)
        self.Frame_buttons.grid(column=0, row=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=1, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

        self.Frame_text_area = Frame(master)
        self.Frame_text_area.grid(column=0, row=1, rowspan=1, columnspan=1, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

        self.verify_numss_button = Button(self.Frame_buttons, stat='normal', text="Check", command=self.verify, width=10)
        self.verify_numss_button.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=W)

        self.main_text = Text(self.Frame_text_area, width=45, height=10)
        self.main_text.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

        self.main_text.tag_config("red", foreground="red")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyFrame().mainloop()
```

Comment: deleting and reinserting the text seems wasteful. Are you aware you can highlight text that has already been inserted, and that the text widget has the ability to search for strings and regular expressions?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what this code is supposed to do, but you clearly have an error on this line:

```
if item not in (alphabet or punctuation_list):
```

Any non-empty list is considered `True` when interpreted as a boolean, so `alphabet or punctuation_list` is evaluated to just `alphabet`. `punctuation_list` is never even evaluated, which is also the reason why you did not notice that the variable does not even exist.

Instead, you should try this, which seems to do what you want:

```
if item not in (alphabet + punctuation):
```

Of course, this is a bit wasteful, as it creates a new list each time and then scans the entire list. It would be faster to create a set once before the loop, like `non_numbers = set(alphabet) | set(punctuation)` and then check `item not in non_numbers`... or just test whether `item.is_digit()`.

Also, note that your code currently strips away any trailing numbers.

---

All in all, a much better way might be to just `search` the text for numbers using a regular expression and adding and removing tags accordingly.

```
def verify(self):
    self.main_text.tag_remove("red", "1.0", END) # remove existing markup
    last = "1.0" # search from beginning
    while True:
        # position of next number
        start = self.main_text.search("\d+", last, regexp=True, stopindex=END)
        if start:
            # position of end of number
            last = self.main_text.search("\D|$", start, regexp=True)
            num = self.main_text.get(start, last)
            # get number and compare to 'blacklist'
            if num not in numbers:
                self.main_text.tag_add("red", start, last)
        else:
            break
```

Comment: instead of creating a new list or set, you can just expand the expression (`if (item not in alphabet and item not in punctuation_list)`

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, that's another possibility. But this will still scan the entire list for every character in the text. Lookup in a single set should be faster -- but it probably does not matter much for the application.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the alphabet and punctuation lists. Use regexps.

At the begin:

```
import re
```

Instead of your verify function use this:

```
def verify(self):
    self.content=self.main_text.get("1.0", 'end-1c')
    self.main_text.delete('1.0', END)
    self.content.encode('utf-8')
    numbers_list = re.findall('\d+', self.content)
    for number in numbers_list:
        self.main_text.insert(END, self.content.split(number)[0])
        if number in numbers:
            self.main_text.insert(END, number)
        else:
            self.main_text.insert(END, number, "red")
        content = ''.join(self.content.split(number)[1:])
    return 'break'
```